# HeapCreate vs GetProcessHeap

Tags: winapi, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm new to using Heap Allocation in C++.

I'm tryin to understand the scenario that will force someone to create a private heap instead of using the Process Heap. Isn't Process Heap generally enough for most of the cases?

Thanks
--Ashish

Answer (score 5):

If you have a flurry of transient heap activity, using a private heap for that can be faster than churning on the process heap.  If you start a thread and give it a private heap, it can be thread-safe in those heap operation without needing to deal with locking for them. There are other reasons, but these two are relatively common ones.

Answer (score 1):

It is an easy way of using a memory pool, which is useful especially on deallocation: Instead of tracking the lifetime of many small objects and deleting them one after another, create a seperate heap for them and destroy the entire heap when you're done.